# How can I define and resolve a GraphQL union type that maps to a google protobuf Oneof field?

Tags: graphql, protocol-buffers, graphql-js, union-types

Environment:

- frontend: nestJS, apollo graphQL, react typescript
- backend: protobuf messages, java

I am trying to resolve a union type in GraphQL using data from backend sent from protobuf "oneof" types, and running into some difficulties... Does anyone have experience with the same?

thanks for reading through the example! I know it's a bit long... appreciate any pointers!!

for example:
given this protobuf definition:

```
message Digest {
  int32 digestId = 1;
  string digestContent = 2;
}
 
message Alert {
  string alertMsg = 1;
}

message ContentWrapper {
  oneof content {
    Digest digest = 1;
    Alert alert = 2;
    string generic = 3;
  }
}
```

the backend response for a list of `ContentWrapper`  items would look like:

```
{
  digest: {
    digestId: 4588283,
    digestContent: 'testmsgasdasdasd'
  },
  alert: undefined,
  generic: undefined
},
{
  alert: {
    alertMsg: 'testmsgasdasdasd'
  },
  digest: undefined,
  generic: undefined
}
```

and with the corresponding union type

```
type ContentWrapper {
  content: ContentUnion
}
 
union ContentUnion =
    Digest
  | Alert
  | String
 
type Digest {
  digestId: Int
  digestMsg: String
}
 
type Alert {
  alertMsg: String
}
```

how would I write my resolveType function?
the problem is in the data returned by backend, there is no `content` field that I can access directly, but rather just each individual possible fields...

therefore, when I try to resolve `ContentWrapper` item, I can't do things like:

```
_resolveType(obj, contextValue, info){
      if(obj.digestId){
        return 'Digest';
      }
      if(obj.alertMsg){
        return 'Alert';
      }
      return null; // GraphQLError is thrown
    },
```

because `obj` is actually the entire `ContentWrapper` =

```
{
  digest: {
    digestId: 4588283,
    digestContent: 'testmsgasdasdasd'
  },
  alert: undefined,
  generic: undefined
}
```

rather than just the nested field of the union types...

Answer (score 0):

Only one of the subtypes is going to be defined in the `ContentWrapper`, correct?

If that's the case then:

```
_resolveType({ digest, alert, generic }, contextValue, info){
  if (digest) return digest;
  else if (alert) return alert;
  else if (generic) return generic;
  // can it ever be none of the above?
},
```